# Is there a way to find the age of an element in a Global window?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using Global Windows for my application with a custom trigger and custom evictor based on some conditions. Now, I also want to evict those elements from the window that have stayed there for too long, let's say 30 mins. How would I go about doing this? Is there a utility that Flink provides that lets me know what the age of an element in a window is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Evictor is passed an `EvictorContext` that provides access to the current watermark and the current processing time. If you timestamp your stream elements then you should have everything you need.